# DidSelectRow is not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

Pretty much what the title says: `DidSelectRow` is not getting called, and I did check that I didn't use `Deselect`. I also checked that `delegate` and `DataSource` are connected to the `tableViewController` and the `Selection` was `Single Selection`. However, the method is still not getting called.

Does an empty `tableView` might have any effect to it(reason it's empty is because the user starts to populate it. I'm using `CoreData` for it)?

**EDIT**

This is what the method looks like:

```
 var effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
    var effect: UIVisualEffect!
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var userMagazineTitle = [User]()
    var dataString = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addProgrammatically()

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<User> = User.fetchRequest()
        do{
            let users = try PresistanceService.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            self.userMagazineTitle = users
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }catch{
            ProgressHUD.showError("Nothing to see here")
        }

    } 

 / MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return userMagazineTitle.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyFeedTableViewCell
        cell.myHeadline?.text = userMagazineTitle[indexPath.row].title
        cell.indentationLevel = 3
        return cell
    }

    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let manage = PresistanceService.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let del = userMagazineTitle[indexPath.row]

        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            manage.delete(del)
            do{
                try manage.save()
            }catch{
                ProgressHUD.showError()
            }

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "User")

            do{
                userMagazineTitle = try manage.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [User]
            }catch{
                ProgressHUD.showError()
            }
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showUser", sender: indexPath)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showUser" {
            let DestViewController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let targetController = DestViewController.topViewController as! CompanyTableViewController
            let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
            let user = userMagazineTitle[indexPath.row].title
            let user2 = userMagazineTitle[indexPath.row].rssurl
            targetController.customUserInit(articlesindex: indexPath.row, title: user!, rssUrl: user2!)
        }

    }

    func addProgrammatically() {
        effectView.frame = view.bounds
        tableView.addSubview(effectView)

        effectView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            effectView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            effectView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        }
        effectView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        effectView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true

        effect = effectView.effect
        effectView.effect = nil

        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "myMagazines.jpg"))
        tableView.backgroundView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        tableView.clipsToBounds = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    }

}
```

Comment: if there is no row then how yo can select that?(as you mentioned that table is empty).

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati It starts off empty until the user populates the TableView

Comment: can you please add code of cellForRow?

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati see edit

Comment: are you able to scroll the tableview? check clip subviews(clip to bounds) for tableview superview. If tableview is not visible after setting this property true, then its an issue with your view's frames.

Comment: @PuneetSharma yeah it's set. should I post the tableView file? some parts

Comment: the function `didSelectRow` will not get called unless there are rows to press. Populate the table view with data that you generate so you have rows that you can test on.

Comment: Yes Alex, that can help us understand the issue better

Comment: @kbunarjo see edit

Comment: @kbunarjo thats not working wither even if I populate it. I also check some other methods like the editing method and it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have added a `UIVisualEffectView` view on top of tableview, which is not passing the touch events to tableview.

Setting `effectView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`, should make this view pass touch events to the views underneath.

Answer (score 11):

Another thing that might lead to the issue is not selected selection kind. I lost my two hours for fixing this.

[image]

Cross check cell selection , if it is selected for no selection change it to single selection.
To do this programatically :

Swift : `tableView.allowsSelection = YES;`

Objective C: `[tableView allowsSelection : YES];`

==============================

This might be helpful to someone!

Answer (score 0):

There could be two issues for this problem:

1. The method signature of the TableView DidSelectRow could be wrong. The current signature is:

   Swift: 
   `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

   ObjectiveC: - `(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
2. You are setting the Delegate of the TableView to nil somewhere in the code.

Comment: I checked the method and delegate, I also deleted the old TableViewController and added another tableViewController.